# How to create a D-Bus server with zbus in Rust?

Tags: rust, apple-m1, dbus

I'm currently trying to implement the example Server code from the [zbus doc](https://docs.rs/zbus/latest/zbus/#server).

I copied the code and changed the path at `serve_at()`:

```
let greeter = Greeter {count: 0};
     let _ = ConnectionBuilder::session()?
             .name("org.zbus.MyGreeter")?
             .serve_at("/Users/jan/Documents/MyGreeter", greeter)?
             .build()
             .await?;
```

After some debugging I figured out that the error comes from the named function:

`Error: Io(Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" })`

I'm using a Mac with a M1 CPU, installed, and started the dbus service but that didn't helped.
What do I do wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late response but I just accidentally stumbled on this.

The example code will only work out-of-the-box on non-Linux machines. It requires a session bus broker/daemon. You can install and run a dbus reference implementation or use [peer-to-peer connection](https://docs.rs/zbus/latest/zbus/struct.ConnectionBuilder.html#method.p2p).